# Running plot() of a DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, fonts

I get the below error when I plot my DataFrame in pandas.

```
   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1236: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['monospace'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
      (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1246: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=medium. Returning /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/cmex10.ttf
      UserWarning)
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1246: UserWarning: findfont: Could not match :family=Bitstream Vera Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=large. Returning /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/cmex10.ttf
      UserWarning)
```

*Help is appreciated:)*

Comment: I think you're trying to use a font (monospace) that you don't have so you're getting a warning that matplotlib will use another font.  Does anything plot?

Comment: @BobHaffner Yes, the graph is fine, but all labels become messy code. How could I install those fonts in matplotlib?

Comment: In addition to @farenorth's question, how are you setting your font family?

Comment: How did you install matplotlib? Did you install it over pip or apt-get (if your using a Debian based machine)?

Comment: @farenorth My OS is Ununtu 14

Comment: @BobHaffner I have no idea how to set it. I did not do any setting on my font family since last installation.

Comment: @MichaelAquilina I installed it using apt-get python3-matplotlib

Comment: Do you have some sample data from your dataframe? If you could just send us DataFrame.head() that should clarify most of the errors.

Comment: @andrewwowens OK, I am working on this tutorial file (the error info appears immediately when I run plot() in the second `In [3]` box): http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/Chapter%204%20-%20Find%20out%20on%20which%20weekday%20people%20bike%20the%20most%20with%20groupby%20and%20aggregate.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Re: Bob Haffner's comment. You can check to see if the monospace font is installed.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.font_manager.findfont('monospace')
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/VeraMono.ttf
```

This is where my matplotlib is looking for the font, and finds it. I suspect that if you did this, you might get a similar error to the one above.

I think you can link to a specific font file like this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/font_file.html

Comment: My interpreter outputs: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f287065843c5> in <module>()
      1 import matplotlib
----> 2 matplotlib.font_manager.findfont('monospace')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'font_manager'`

Comment: Try this import statement instead.  import matplotlib.font_manager

Comment: @BobHaffner Fine, this time my output is `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf`, no error info. But when I use `plot()` in pandas, the error info still shows up

Comment: Ok, I'm surprised.  Like @tandy, I thought it would give you an error

Comment: "If your version of matplotlib is 1.3 or lower, setting the display.mpl_style to 'default' with pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default' to produce more appealing plots. When set, matplotlib’s rcParams are changed (globally!) to nicer-looking settings." 

Can you set pd.options.display.mpl_style= 'default' in the top of your script and try to re-run? And if not this, can you try = False? 

Also, can you please paste your imports and code leading up to .plot() Thanks!

Comment: @tandy Hi, I set mpl_style to default and False just now, but none of them works. And I am working on this tutorial file (the error info appears immediately when I run plot() in the second In [3] box): http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/Chapter%204%20-%20Find%20out%20on%20which%20weekday%20people%20bike%20the%20most%20with%20groupby%20and%20aggregate.ipynb

Comment: Pasted in your question, is that the full stack trace, too?

Comment: @username123 Also, can you run: 
`import matplotlib`
Then, `matplotlib.rcParams['datapath']`
Then copy that directory, cd into it, cd into fonts, do you have stuff in there?

Comment: @tandy Yes, it is the full stack. And in my fonts directory under `/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/` there are three files: afm  pdfcorefonts  ttf

Comment: `cd ttf; ls` -- What are the results of this -- do you have a bunch of .ttf files? Do you have VeraMono.ttf ?

Comment: @tandy it is `cmb10.ttf          STIXGeneralItalic.ttf  STIXSizOneSymReg.ttf
cmex10.ttf      STIXGeneral.ttf        STIXSizThreeSymBol.ttf
cmmi10.ttf     STIXNonUniBolIta.ttf   STIXSizThreeSymReg.ttf
cmr10.ttf      STIXNonUniBol.ttf    STIXSizTwoSymBol.ttf
cmss10.ttf       STIXNonUniIta.ttf     STIXSizTwoSymReg.ttf
cmsy10.ttf        STIXNonUni.ttf    VeraMono-Bold-Italic.ttf
cmtt10.ttf        STIXSizFiveSymReg.ttf  VeraMono-Bold.ttf
LICENSE_STIX    STIXSizFourSymBol.ttf  VeraMono-Italic.ttf
STIXGeneralBolIta.ttf  STIXSizFourSymReg.ttf  VeraMono.ttf
STIXGeneralBol.ttf     STIXSizOneSymBol.ttf
`

Comment: OK, try running this 
`import matplotlib.font_manager`

`matplotlib.font_manager.findfont('monospace',fallback_to_default=False, rebuild_if_missing=True, directory='/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf')`

Comment: @tandy It is still the same

Comment: What is the path it is choosing, /usr/share/fonts/truetype/? What I'm thinking is that when findfont is being called, it is looking for fonts in the wrong directory. This could have to do with how you installed matplotlib (as mentioned by people in previous comments).

Comment: @tandy It is choosing `/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf`. Is it better  to install all packages with `pip3` instead of `apt-get`?

Comment: @tandy Although I still have no idea why, but when I change the default font using `matplotlib.rc('font', family='sans-serif')`, everything works fine!